# find elements of string that ends with specific value

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings

```
['time_10', 'time_23', 'time_345', 'date_10', 'date_23', 'date_345']
```

I want to use regular expression to get strings that end with a specific number.

As I understand, first I have to combine all strings from the list into large string, then use form some kind of a pattern to use it for regular expression

I would be grateful if you could provide

```
regex(some_pattern, some_string)
```

that would return

```
['time_10', 'date_10']
```

or just

```
'time_10, date_10'
```

Comment: What's wrong with `endswith(..)`? `[x for x in data if x.endswith(str(query))]`...

Comment: nothing wrong, but I wanted to know if it is possible to use regex. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Demaunt, yes, it's possible

Comment: What about `10$` as regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) is enough.

```
l = ['time_10', 'time_23', 'time_345', 'date_10', 'date_23', 'date_345']

result = [s for s in l if s.endswith('10')]

print(result)
['time_10', 'date_10']
```

---

If you insist on using regex,

```
import re
result = [s for s in l if re.search('10$', s)]
```